# Continuity of $f(x) = \left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2},\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, stereographic-projections

I am looking at [a proof that shows $S^1$ is a topological manifold](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucaheps/papers/Manifolds%202016.pdf), where the author defines this function:
$$
f_1^{-1}: \mathbb R \to S^1 \setminus \{(0,-1)\}
$$
by
$$
f_1^{-1}(x) = \biggl( \frac{2x}{1+x^2},\, \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2} \biggr).
$$
(Here $S^1$ is defined as the unit circle on $\mathbb R^2$ equipped with the subspace topology.) The author claims that the function is "evidently continuous when viewed as a function to $\mathbb R^2$". Can anyone provide an explanation to this claim? I know it is probably true if I just play around with the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument, but is there a more obvious explanation?

Comment: Yes, rational functions are continuous away from their poles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rational functions whose denominators are never zero are continuous and a function taking values in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous if and only if it is coordinate-wise continuous. Both of these things imply your function is continuous.